# Easiest way to run code in Shopware6 framework / context

Tags: shopware, shopware6

While developing a shopware6 module, I sometimes want to test a few lines of code, to see if I'm moving the right direction.
Let's say I want to run the following code (ignoring that I would use xDebug)

```
$container = $kernel->getContainer();
$customRepository = $container->get('foobar.repository');
...
var_dump($customId); die();
```

How / Where can I incorporate that without creating too much of an overhead, and without altering anything in /vendor? I tried it in index.php, but as soon as we have the framework loaded, there a re already several paths that can be taken.

Thanks

Comment: I'd write a command, it is kind of simple to setup and easily reusable. Or you could write some tests and check your code there.

Comment: what about writing that in a test? so you directly test the stuff you are building ;-)

Comment: +1 for writing tests for that, that way you can ensure that your code snippet not just works once, but stays working as other stuff changes. Refer to this [doc article](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/plugin-testing) on how to setup PHPUnit for your plugin.

Comment: Tests are great for the "done" code, but for the explorative development they can be cumbersome. In short, sometimes you just want to take a peak at something. I reworded the question for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom plugin, with a Command class. There is a good guide [here](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/plugin-commands), and it includes a link to the Symfony docs, and a github repo with sample code.

I would recommend installing the plugin with the `bin/console plugin:etc` type commands - you get much better error reporting than if you do it via the web interface.